# How can I draw the following background image?

Tags: flutter

How can I draw the following background image? I tried with Waves Clipper. I am getting very different results.

[image]

thank you,

Comment: Does that image move? Or is it static? If it's static I'd just import it as a .png

Answer (score 0):

Look if [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/wave) can work for you.

You can animate waves, set colors, blur, and gradient. And it's `null safety`.

[image]